# How to install package ddccontrol in the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

I use the `14.04 LTS` version of `Ubuntu` and I bought a `Dell` monitor model `UltraSharp 24 Monitor U2415`, however I am not able to use it. I have tried to install the `ddccontrol` package but when I execute the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ddccontrol
```

The following message appears:

```
Unable to find ddccontrol package
```

How do I use the new monitor in Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not very sure that package will fix your issue, what the problem with the screen?

Comment: Hello @olivierb2, now that I noticed a DP-miniDP cable came, however my notebook does not have a miniDP input and I've been searching it seems the monitor does not support the DP-HDMI cable. I no longer know what I can do in this case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how do you connect your screen in that case, and how you are planning to fix your issue with ddcontrol. What kind of connection are available on your laptop?